# docker-compose doesn't set the proxy in service container

Tags: magento, proxy, docker-compose

I am trying to set the proxy on a magento-devbox (I asked also on the magento stack, but there seems to be less people: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182414/devbox-with-magento2-2-1-6-doesnt-reach-the-proxy-in-docker-container).

I tried the following:

- added an `.env` file with `http_proxy=myip`
- added the `http_proxy=myip` directly in the docker-compose.yml under `environment` section of the service

The strange thing: the installation of the webshop (thing are downloaded) and the containers itself work => at running time the proxy works.

When I ssh in the container and run `env` the variable is not there. So if I try `curl www.google.de` will not work. If I set the proxy manually will work again (`export http_proxy=myip`), but this will be set only for this session and I need to reach the internate from the webshop too.

LE: if I go and run `docker-compose exec --user magento2 web env` I will see the right http_proxy settings (also as root works). But when I ssh (with putty or in PHPStorm) in the container and I do `env`, these settings are not there anymore.

Do you have any ideas what can I do more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem: everytime when I started a ssh the `http_proxy` variable was not initiated.

For that I had to change the `/etc/profile` and add there the `export http_proxy = my ip`. This should be done each time after creating the container!